# Match whole world using Like operator in snowflake query

Tags: sql-server, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have sql server query below that search a complete string "school" from one or more column of sql server.

I want to have same query result in snowflake. As I am facing some challenges to have same case insensitive results in snowflake.

```
Create table Table1(Id int identity(1,1),col1 varchar(max),col2 varchar(max),col3 varchar(max),col4 varchar(max),col5 varchar(max))

Insert into Table1(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5) Values ('This is my school','This is schooling string','This is test string','This is test string','This is test string')
Insert into Table1(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5) Values ('This is my school','This school is mine','This is test string','This is test string','This is test string')

Insert into Table1(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5) Values ('This is my school','This is test string','This is intermediate School','This is test string','This is test string')
Insert into Table1(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5) Values ('This is my school','This school is mine','This is test string','Schooling','This is test string')

Insert into Table1(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5) Values ('This is my schooling','This schooling is mine','This is test string','Schooling','5 Years schooling')

select * from Table1
Declare @KEYWORD Varchar(100)
SET @KEYWORD='school'
Select * from Table1 
      WHERE (
            '.' + Col1 + '.' LIKE '%[^A-Z]' + @KEYWORD + '[^A-Z]%'
            OR '.' + Col2 + '.' LIKE '%[^A-Z]' + @KEYWORD + '[^A-Z]%'
            OR '.' + Col3 + '.' LIKE '%[^A-Z]' + @KEYWORD + '[^A-Z]%'
            OR '.' + Col4 + '.' LIKE '%[^A-Z]' + @KEYWORD + '[^A-Z]%'
            OR '.' + Col5 + '.' LIKE '%[^A-Z]' + @KEYWORD + '[^A-Z]%'
            )
```

Comment: Seems like you should be look at full text indexing. Also, however, do you *really* have rows which need to store up to 10 GB of characters..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [RLIKE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/rlike.html):

```
SET KEYWORD = 'school';

SELECT * 
FROM Table1 
WHERE RLIKE(Col1, '(^|.*[^A-Z])' ||  $KEYWORD || '([^A-Z].*|$)', 'i')
   OR RLIKE(Col2, '(^|.*[^A-Z])' ||  $KEYWORD || '([^A-Z].*|$)', 'i')
   OR RLIKE(Col3, '(^|.*[^A-Z])' ||  $KEYWORD || '([^A-Z].*|$)', 'i')
   OR RLIKE(Col4, '(^|.*[^A-Z])' ||  $KEYWORD || '([^A-Z].*|$)', 'i')
   OR RLIKE(Col5, '(^|.*[^A-Z])' ||  $KEYWORD || '([^A-Z].*|$)', 'i');
```

Pattern is case-insensitive:

- start of string or anything + character that is not letter
- then KEYWORD
- charactrer that is not letter + anything or end of string